# Validation required for zip codes less than 6 digits

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery, zipcode

we have [custom module](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cashondelivery-based-on-zipcode.html) for **entering zip codes in backend**, only if those zip codes if we enter in shipping address, than it will display COD under payment method , otherwise it will hide COD.

[image]

Here problem is it is working only for 6 digits.

if we enter any **below 6 digit zip codes** in shipping address , its displaying COD. This is **problem**.

ex: 2,24, 246, 2468, 12345

but if we enter **any 6 digit zip codes** other than zipcodes which is present backend, its not displaying COD. This is **fine.**

ex: 123456, 333999, 666666

as validation is working fine for 6 digits we want for other digits also.

**Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Mfp_Cod_Model_Observer {

    public function getCashOnDelvery(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event           = $observer->getEvent();
        $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
        $result          = $event->getResult();
        $isModuleEnable = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/enable');

        if($isModuleEnable) {

            if($method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery' ){

                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                $add = $quote->getShippingAddress();
                $postcode = $add->getData('postcode');

                $comparisonMode = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/mode');
                $zipCodes = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/zipcode');
                $isExist = false;

                if(trim($zipCodes) == '') {             
                    $result->isAvailable = true;
                } else {    

                    if(strpos($zipCodes, $postcode) !==  false) {
                        $isExist = true;
                    }


                    if($isExist != true) {

                        $zipCodesArray = explode(',', nl2br($zipCodes));
                        if(count($elementLineArray) > 1) {
                            foreach($zipCodesArray as $codzipLine) {
                                $elementLineArray = explode('-', $codzipLine);
                                if(count($elementLineArray) == 2 && ( $postcode >= $elementLineArray[0] && $postcode <= $elementLineArray[1] )) {
                                    $isExist = true;
                                    break;
                                } else if($postcode == $codzipLine) {
                                    $isExist = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $returnValue = '';
                        $returnValue = ($isExist)?true:false;

                    $result->isAvailable = $returnValue;

                }   

            } 
        }   
    }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mfp_Cod>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Mfp_Cod>
  </modules>
  <global>
          <models>
            <cod>
                <class>Mfp_Cod_Model</class>
            </cod>
        </models>

    <helpers>
      <cod>
        <class>Mfp_Cod_Helper</class>
      </cod>
    </helpers>
  </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <payment_method_is_active>
                <observers>
                    <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Mfp_Cod_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>getCashOnDelvery</method>
                    </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                </observers>
            </payment_method_is_active>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in `Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Mfp_Cod_Model_Observer 
{

    public function getCashOnDelvery(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event           = $observer->getEvent();
        $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
        $result          = $event->getResult();
        $isModuleEnable = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/enable');
        $returnValue = false;
        if($isModuleEnable) {

            if($method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery' ){

                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                $add = $quote->getShippingAddress();
                $postcode = $add->getData('postcode');
                $comparisonMode = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/mode');
                $zipCodes = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/zipcode');
                $isExist = false;
                if(strlen($postcode) >= 6) {
                    if(trim($zipCodes) == '') {             
                        $result->isAvailable = true;
                    } else {    

                        if(strpos($zipCodes, $postcode) !==  false) {
                            $isExist = true;
                        }

                        if($isExist != true) {

                            $zipCodesArray = explode(',', nl2br($zipCodes));
                            if(count($elementLineArray) > 1) {
                                foreach($zipCodesArray as $codzipLine) {
                                    $elementLineArray = explode('-', $codzipLine);
                                    if(count($elementLineArray) == 2 && ( $postcode >= $elementLineArray[0] && $postcode <= $elementLineArray[1] )) {
                                        $isExist = true;
                                        break;
                                    } else if($postcode == $codzipLine) {
                                        $isExist = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $returnValue = ($isExist)?true:false;
                        $result->isAvailable = $returnValue;
                    }
                }
                $result->isAvailable = $returnValue;   

            } 
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: now its not allowing for  zip codes i entered in backend also.

Comment: updated ans pls check now

Comment: this is class, whenever and all i am in some big problem you will come & help me, Thanks a lot buddy. you are my life saver :-)